# How to name txt file, created with VBA using Listbox Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have my first quite large project, and I can't do only this. 
There are different values saved to txt, that depends on selected item in ListBox, therefore I want to name the file accordingly. 
With this code file is named "ListBox1.txt"

````
Dim File As String
Dim i, n
File = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ListBox1.Name & ".txt"
Open File For Output As #1
For n = 2 To 7
If Line.ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
For i = 0 To Line.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Line.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
       Data = " " & Cells(i + 2, n).Value
    End If
Next i
End If
Print #1, Cells(1, n) & ":" & Data
Next n
Close #1
MsgBox ("File is saved in the same folder with current file")
End Sub```
````

Comment: You should use `ListBox1.Text` instead of `ListBox1.Name`. Another alternative would be `ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)`.

Comment: So easy) Thank you so much